# How can I display the iPhone keyboard when an image has focus?

Tags: jquery, iphone, css, ios

If a textarea or input (type text) element has focus in a HTML page running in an iPhone has focus, then the iPhone keyboard will display.

However, I have an Image ( tag), and I would like to be able to display the iPhone keyboard when this element has focus, and capture keypress events.

I have read that the CSS style -webkit-user-modify: read-write; is supposed to do this, but it does not appear to be working in the iOS simulator.

I'm using JQuery Mobile, without any native Cocoa/Objective C code.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send focus to a hidden text field (`position: relative; left:-10000px;` for the CSS style) when the image is clicked, and when that text field loses focus, the value of that text field is the text the user entered.

```
$("#myImg").click(function() {
    $("#inputOutsideOfPageAndUnviewable").blur(function() {
         var myImageTag = $("#inputOutsideOfPageAndUnviewable").val();
    });
    $("#inputOutsideOfPageAndUnviewable").focus();
});
```

Comment: I was writing something like that +1 for your speed ;)